# wpf two scrollbars value syncing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

First scroll bar represents value from min value to second scroll bar, and second scroll bar represents value from min to max value.

So when i change my max or min value my second scroll bar works correctly(scailing). And also when i use my first scroll bar my second one doesn't scale - how it should be.

The problem occurs when i am using second scroll bar and setting my current value lower then value of first scroll bar. Is it possible somehow change first scroll bar value when my second scroll bar value becoming lower than (max value of first scroll bar). Somehow sync max value of first scroll bar and current value of second one, so when i set second scroll bar value lower than max value of first, it also change first scroll bar max value.

```
<ScrollBar Name="FirstScrollBar" 
    Minimum="{Binding Path=startValue}" 
    Maximum="{Binding Path=yellowFinishTag, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Value="{Binding Path=redFinishTag, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<ScrollBar Name="SecondScrollBar" 
    Minimum="{Binding Path=startValue,  Mode=TwoWay}"
    Maximum="{Binding Path=endValue,  Mode=TwoWay}"
    Value="{Binding Path=yellowFinishTag,  Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Model:

```
    public class Scale
{
    public float startValue { get; set; }
    public float endValue { get; set; }

    public float redFinishTag { get; set; }

    public float yellowFinishTag { get; set; }

    //Marks
    public float markFromValue { get; set; }
    public float markToValue { get; set; }

    public Scale()
    {

    }

    public ScaleDTO(float startValue, float endValue, float redFinishTag, float yellowFinishTag)
    {
        this.startValue = startValue;
        this.endValue = endValue;

        this.redFinishTag = redFinishTag;
        this.yellowFinishTag = yellowFinishTag;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I have added MVVM approach to my project in order to fix it.
My ScaleViewModel:

```
    public class ScaleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Scale scale;

    public ScaleViewModel()
    {
        scale = new Scale(0,100,0,0);
    }

    public Scale Scale
    {
        get
        {
            return scale;
        }
        set
        {
            scale = value;
        }
    }

    public float StartValue
    {
        get { return scale.startValue; }
        set
        {
            if (scale.startValue != value)
            {
                scale.startValue = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("StartValue");

            }
        }
    }

    public float EndValue
    {
        get { return scale.endValue; }
        set
        {
            if (scale.endValue != value)
            {
                scale.endValue = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("EndValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public float RedFinishTag
    {
        get { return scale.redFinishTag; }
        set
        {
            if (scale.redFinishTag != value)
            {
                scale.redFinishTag = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("RedFinishTag");
            }
        }
    }

    public float YellowFinishTag
    {
        get { return scale.yellowFinishTag; }
        set
        {
            if (scale.yellowFinishTag != value)
            {
                scale.yellowFinishTag = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("YellowFinishTag");
            }
        }
    }

    public float MarkFromValue
    {
        get { return scale.markFromValue; }
        set
        {
            if (scale.markFromValue != value)
            {
                scale.markFromValue = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MarkFromValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public float MarkToValue
    {
        get { return scale.markToValue; }
        set
        {
            if (scale.markToValue != value)
            {
                scale.markToValue = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MarkToValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // take a copy to prevent thread issues
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Also i have changed DataContext and binding values in my XAML.
[image: scroll bars]

Red top border value is higher than yellow one.
[image: red top border scroll bar value incorect]

Everything works fine when i add this bad code:

```
                if (Scale.YellowFinishTag < Scale.RedFinishTag)
            {
                Scale.RedFinishTag = Scale.YellowFinishTag;
            }
```

Comment: are you using MVVM?

Comment: Do you rise notifications in your properties? Show us the code contatining `startValue`, etc.

Comment: @Default i am trying to but i am not sure i am. Still new to WPF

Comment: @Sinatr yes sorry, done

Comment: Properties that you want to bind to should be on view-models that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Whenever a property changes (use the property setter), the view-model should raise the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event, passing in the name of the property.  This is how the view generated from the XAML actually sees the changing values of the properties.  Without this, the view can't properly react to those changing properties.  This is usually done by having some kind of base class for the view-model, with a simple method for the property setter to call that raises the event.

Comment: You are not implementing notifications, so second control has no clue what value was changed by first and vice-versa. Start from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification). Also check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/fzcth91k(v=vs.71)).